# android нехватка памяти при http post

Tags: android, c#, http

Клиент на андроиде отправляет на сервер несколько картинок кодированных в base64. При большом размере картинок возникает ошибка нехватки памяти

```
public class encImages extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String[] args){
        encryptedImages=new String[imageUris.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<checkedPathes.size();i++){
            try{
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(checkedPathes.get(i));
                bmp=transformImage.rotate(bmp,transformImage.getOrientation(checkedPathes.get(i)));
                encryptedImages[i]=transformImage.encbase64(bmp)
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        readyText="image[sep]"+TextUtils.join("[imagesep]",encryptedImages);
        new sendmsg().execute(ip,port,readyText);
    }
}

private class sendmsg extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] args){
        webRequest request=new webRequest();
        HashMap<String,String> param=new HashMap<>();
        param.put("text",args[2]);

        return request.run("http://"+args[0]+":"+args[1], "POST", param);
    }
}
```

**webRequest.java**

```
public class webRequest {
    webRequest(){}

    String run(String urladdress, String requestmethod, HashMap<String,String> params){
        URL url;
        StringBuilder fullUrl=new StringBuilder();
        String response="";
        int reqresponsecode=0;

        if(requestmethod.equals("GET")){
            try{
                fullUrl.append(urladdress);
                if(params!=null){
                    fullUrl.append("?");
                    fullUrl.append(getQueryString(params));
                }

                url=new URL(fullUrl.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod(requestmethod);
                response=getResponse(conn);
            }
            catch(Exception e){response=e.toString();}

        }

        else if(requestmethod.equals("POST")){
            try {
                url=new URL(urladdress);

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(100);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                writer.write(getQueryString(params).toString());

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                response=getResponse(conn);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response.equals("")?"no response-2"+reqresponsecode:response;

    }

    private StringBuilder getQueryString(HashMap<String,String> params){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        try{
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        return result;
    }

    private String getResponse(HttpURLConnection connection){
        String response="";
        int code=0;
        try{
            code=connection.getResponseCode();
            if (code == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                    response+=line;
            }
            else
                 response="no response-1. code: "+code;
        }
        catch (Exception e){}

        return response.equals("")?"no response-2. code: "+code:response;
    }
}
```

Как можно отправить большой объем данных? в пределах допустим 20-30 мБ?